# How To Isolate $y$ In This Complicated Equation?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've been working on a geometry/trig problem in my spare time, which is concisely displayed here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tt5sh99igg. 
 If you don't want to look at the desmos link (which you don't have to), I basically have ∆ABC and random Point P (all of which are on a normal cartesian coordinate plane).  I've thought of a few things that I'd like to derive from these givens, but the one I'm working on right now is this: Express all Points $P$ for any $\Delta ABC$ where $PA+PB+PC$ equals the perimeter of $\Delta ABC$.  I had been trying to look for an alternative other than painful painful algebra, but unfortunately I haven't found one yet, so I decided to brute force the algebra.  Here's the beast:

$$\sqrt{\left ( a_x-b_x \right )^2 + (a_y-b_y)^2}+\sqrt{\left ( b_x-c_x \right )^2 + (b_y-c_y)^2}+\sqrt{\left ( c_x-a_x \right )^2 + (c_y-a_y)^2}=\sqrt{\left ( a_x-x \right )^2 + (a_y-y)^2}+\sqrt{\left ( b_x-x \right )^2 + (b_y-y)^2}+\sqrt{\left ( c_x-x \right )^2 + (c_y-y)^2}$$

So, I have a few questions.  Is it possible to solve this (in terms of $y$)?  Are there other non-brute force methods to either solve this equation or derive the solution I'm looking for?  Is there a way to simplify this (in addition to having point (*a<sub>x</sub>*, *a<sub>y</sub>*) = (*0*, *0*))?  And lastly, if you happen to think of anything else that would be fun or interesting to derive with these givens, please suggest below!

EDIT (for clarification): *$x$* and *$y$* are unknown variables.  The variables *a<sub>x</sub>*, *a<sub>y</sub>*, *b<sub>x</sub>*, *b<sub>y</sub>*, *c<sub>x</sub>*, and *c<sub>y</sub>* are all known constants.

EDIT 2: A user commented that a combination of three equations for part of an ellipse would work.  Or in other words, three functions of an ellipse, one with foci at points $A$ and $B$, another with foci at $B$ and $C$, and the last with foci at points $C$ and $A$.  After testing this myself, I've concluded this isn't correct.  In addition to using a paper which @Kajelad linked in the comments section, might there be any other methods of finding a solution?

Comment: and the variable $x$ is known here?

Comment: I edited my original post to help clarify this, but to answer your question directly, x and y are unknown variables, the other six variables are known constants.

Comment: I think the comment was directed at your asking for a solution in terms of $y$, when you actually want to solve for $x,y$ in terms of the known quantities, or more likely, for $y$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: I'm only 80% sure I fully understand what you're saying, but $(x, y)$ is not just one point however, its a shape (remotely eliptical) on a graph.  Basically, what I'm looking for is $y$ in terms of variable $x$ and the six other constants.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  You get some equation $f(x,y)=0.$  "Solving the equation"  usually means finding an expression for $y$ in terms of $x$.  Your question says "Is it possible to solve this (in terms of $y$)" and I think that Dr. Graubner was suggesting you rephrase this.

Comment: It's good that you've tried some examples to find that you get a closed curve (remotely elliptical as you say.)  You should state this **in the body of your question.**  The more work you indicate you've done, the more help you're liable to get.  People don't always read the comments.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, I'd appreciate being able to give it a try myself first.  Thank you so much!  Like really, I can't thank you enough!  I both cannot believe and completely believe (yes there is a contradiction in terms) that I didn't think of that!  Now for the tedious work to begin!

Comment: The curve you are presenting is an [N-ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse) (specifically, a 3-ellipse). There is a bit of literature, but functional forms are hard to come by. [This paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-0-387-75155-9_7.pdf) presents an exact formula for general $N$ that allows you to write a polynomial in $x$ and $y$; unfortunately in the case of $N=3$ this is a polynomial represented by the determinant of an $8\times 8$ matrix, the expansion of which has $2355$ terms. I doubt the solutions have a simple closed form.

Comment: Thank you Kajelad, although to my knowledge Desmos doesn't support matrixes, but I can still use a more powerful engine (although old, I find Mac OSX's Grapher application to be incredibly useful for advanced mathematics and modeling, or even just things that other apps can't do).